# asp.net mvc core web api same pattern actions are not working all times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two action methods in my controller.

```
[Route("users")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("username/{username}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        var response = await _userService.GetUserByUsername(username);

        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search/{term}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string term)
    {
        var response = await _userService.Search(term);

        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

These are same pattern. But sometimes I called `Search` action, it runs `GetUserByUsername` action. Why this occured?

- `http://localhost/users/username/mmyusername   => calls GetUserByUsername`
- `http://localhost/users/search/fra             => calls Search`
- `http://localhost/users/search/français        => returns nothing but 200 ,becaues`
- `http://localhost/users/search?term=fra             => calls GetUserByUsername`

Comment: I have tried the same and it's working in my machine.. 

What is your request url ?

Comment: It's strange . If you use the default routeTemplate `app.UseMvc();` in web api project, you should get 404 error in the fourth request url. What's the related route setting in the Startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[FromUri]` attribute on you Search endpoint, update the method to be as follows;

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromUri] string term)
    {
        var response = await _userService.Search(term);

        return Ok(response);
    }
```